# OpenGL Color By Face

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, graphics, colors

I'm new to OpenGL and theres a small project I'm working on. A part of this project is create a grid which allows for some sections of the grid to have different colors.

E.g. The entire grid is green but a block on the grid is lit red and maybe another one yellow.

What I have done to draw this grid is with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP while using indicies. After that stage, I have also included colors in the same vertex data array. But the output isn't how i want it to be.

Firstly there was an interpolation which i tried to remove by adding the 'flat' flag for the color. But there seem to be a overlapping problem. Which resulted this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDhlk.png).

Is there anyway to create a grid. Where a block of the grid can be of a different color than the grid.

**Update**
Here is my code for GL_TRIANGLES

```
short* Grid::Indicies()
{
    const int X_GRID_SIZE = X_GRID_SIZE_;
    const int Y_GRID_SIZE = Y_GRID_SIZE_;
    const int INDICIES_SIZE = (((X_GRID_SIZE * 4) + ((X_GRID_SIZE_ - 3) * 2)) * Y_GRID_SIZE);

    short* indicies = new short[INDICIES_SIZE];
    int index = 0;

    for (size_t y = 0; y < Y_GRID_SIZE_; y++)
    {
        // Current, Down, Right, Down
        indicies[index++] = (short)(y * X_GRID_SIZE_);
        indicies[index++] = (short)((y + 1) * X_GRID_SIZE_);
        indicies[index++] = (short)((y * X_GRID_SIZE_) + 1);
        indicies[index++] = (short)((y + 1) * X_GRID_SIZE_);

        for (size_t x = 1; x < X_GRID_SIZE_ - 1; x++)
        {
            // Current, Down, Current, Down, Right, Down
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                indicies[index++] = (short)((y * X_GRID_SIZE_) + x);
                indicies[index++] = (short)(((y + 1) * X_GRID_SIZE_) + x);
            }
            indicies[index++] = (short)((y * X_GRID_SIZE_) + x + 1);
            indicies[index++] = (short)(((y + 1) * X_GRID_SIZE_) + x);
        }
        // Current, Down
        indicies[index++] = (short)(((y + 1) * X_GRID_SIZE_) - 1);
        indicies[index++] = (short)(((y + 2) * X_GRID_SIZE_) - 1);
    }
    indicies_size_ = index;
    return (indicies);
}

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    // Position                 // Color
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
    -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
     0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
     1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 

    -1.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
     0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
     1.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 

    -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,       1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
    -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
     0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
     0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
     1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,

    -1.0f, -0.5f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
     0.0f, -0.5f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
     1.0f, -0.5f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 

    -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
    -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
     0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
     0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
     1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,       0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
};

GLuint v_buffer_object, v_array_object, e_buffer_object;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &v_array_object);
glGenBuffers(1, &v_buffer_object);
glGenBuffers(1, &e_buffer_object);

glBindVertexArray(v_array_object);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, v_buffer_object);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, e_buffer_object);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(grid.Indicies()) * grid.IndiciesSize(), grid.Indicies(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindVertexArray(0);

glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`. Use `GL_TRIANGLES` and draw each block with 2 triangles and 4 vertices. Each vertex belongs to only 1 block. Thanks to that you don't have to use 'flat' flag, just change color for 4 vertices at once. You can try to draw each block separate, with space between each other. Then you can connect them by translating vertices and create the grid.

Comment: When you mean don't use GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. Is that because GL_TRIANGLES is more efficient? Or is just because its easier this way?

Comment: It's easier. When you use `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` each triangle share 2 vertices with previous one so it's hard to color them with different color. So you're using 'flat' modifier to hack it. With `GL_TRIANGLES` you have more control

Comment: I implemented the grid using GL_TRIANGLES but the problem still occurs. Would the better solution be creating two fragment shaders. Since i want to make a checkered grid. One shader would be white and the other black? Would that be the better approach? If so how can i do this?

Comment: How do you create and fill vertex and index array?

Answer (score 1):

With `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, flat shading will use the color from vertex *i*+2 to color traingle *i* (this is called the *provoking vertex*).  This doesn't get you what you want.  An easy option is to switch to `GL_TRIANGLES`, and make sure to specify your element indexes so that the same vertex is chosen third for both triangles in each quad (because the third vertex is the provoking vertex for triangles, by default).  For example, suppose these are the vertexes:

```
 0   1   2   3

 4   5   6   7

 8   9  10  11

12  13  14  15
```

Let's look at one of the quads:

```
0---1
|   |
4---5
```

Let's choose vertex 0 to hold the color for the entire quad.  What we then do is make sure that both triangles include vertex 0, and that vertex 0 is last in both triangles.

```
0---1
| \ |
4---5
```

So our index array will be:

```
5 1 0 4 5 0 ...
```

This uses positive (anticlockwise) winding order.

Comment: How would the color be implemented ? I see how the triangles can be manipulated with the index data. But what about color ? Would there be another index for that aswell ? How is it done ? Could you please explain using some data, vertex, index and color

Comment: You would store the color as part of each vertex.  Each vertex would have a location and a color.  You create an array of vertexes.  The data for the array is stored in a buffer.  The indexes are indexes into that array, and you use those indexes with `glDrawElements()`.  This is basic OpenGL, it should be covered by any modern OpenGL tutorial.

Comment: But shouldn't the problem of one vertex having to have two colors still be present ? Such when using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Comment: "Let's choose vertex 0 to hold the color for the entire quad."  The other vertexes hold colors for other quads.  This works because we don't have more vertexes than quads.

Comment: I tried implementing it using the way you suggested. But I still have the problem. I to make it like a grid, vertical and horizontal. And each block is covered with horizontal and vertical lines. But currently they're diagonal. How can i solve this ?

Comment: @JekasG: You want to also draw lines?  Put that in your fragment shader.

Comment: How is the number of elements calculated ?

Comment: Each quad has 6 index elements for two triangles, and the vertex elements are shared between neighboring quads.

Comment: In that case it would be 3*(num_quad) ?

Comment: For vertexes? No.  If you have a 4x5 grid of quads, you'll have 30 vertexes (5x6) and 120 indexes (4x5x6).  If you have a 2x2 grid of quads, you'll have 9 vertexes (3x3) and 24 indexes (2x2x6).